# TreeTable has rendering issue

Tags: sapui5

Using sap.ui.table.TreeTable with a padding of 20px causes a rendering problem. Lines to adjust the column width gets pushed to the left as you can see in the picture. Also when I highlight a row and scroll up and down the page the highlighted box on the far left hand side doesnt scroll accordingly and get stuck in its old place.[image]

Comment: Please provide more details, maybe via Js Bin.

Comment: @matbtt 
So my question is very simple and you can try it your own. In the latest sapui5 (version 1.30) if you apply padding 20px to tree table, you can see that vertical lines which let you move the columns around are pushed to the left and they are not in-line with column lines.